# Pricing a Forward Rate Agreement using QuantLib Python

Tags: python, finance, quantitative-finance, quantlib, financialinstrument

Can someone please help with the pricing of the following forward rate agreement using QuantLib Python?

A 3x6 forward rate agreement, with a notional of $100,000, the FRA rate being 6%, The FRA settlement date is after 3 months (90 days) and the settlement is based on a 90-day USDLIBOR.

My valuation date is 30 June 2020.

This is my attempt:

```py
import QuantLib as ql

startDate = ql.Date(30, 6, 2020)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = startDate

spotDates = [ql.Date(30, 6, 2020), ql.Date(31, 12, 2020), ql.Date(30, 6, 2021)]
spotRates = [0.05, 0.05, 0.05]

dayConvention = ql.Thirty360()
calendar = ql.UnitedStates()

maturityDate = calendar.advance(startDate, ql.Period('3M'))

compounding = ql.Simple
compoundingFrequency = ql.Annual

spotCurve = ql.ZeroCurve(spotDates, spotRates, dayConvention, calendar, ql.Linear(), compounding, compoundingFrequency)
spotCurve.enableExtrapolation()
spotCurveHandle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(spotCurve)

index = ql.USDLibor(ql.Period('3M'), spotCurveHandle)
index.addFixing(ql.Date(26, 6, 2020), 0.05)
notional = 100000
rate = 0.06

fra = ql.ForwardRateAgreement(startDate, maturityDate, ql.Position.Long, rate, notional, index, spotCurveHandle)
print('NPV:', fra.NPV())
```

And this is the answer that I get:

> NPV: 0.0

The answer that I'm getting is not correct.

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an NPV, but it is wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure about the parameters that I have passed... If they are correct or not.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be just under USD 250? You bought the FRA at 6%, and it is likely to fix at 5%. So at settle you've made 1% annualized on $100k, so 100k x 1% x 0.25 = $250? Then there will be a small discount of that 250 to spot (1+0.05)^0.25 = 1.01227. So NPV around USD 247.

Comment: That's why I believe that there is a mistake in my codes... Any help would be most welcomed.

Comment: What NPV do you get?

Comment: I get an NPV of 0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off (for accuracy) the daycount for USD FRAs is Act/360, ie `ql.Actual360()`. Also bear in mind that the fixing calendar for FRAs is based on the UK calendar (BBA Libor), which may be different from the settlement calendar (so 4th July is not a fixing holiday, but is a settlement holiday).

**The main issue with the OP code is that the FRA start date is the same as the evaluation date.** Once you know the fixing, then the FRA is effectively settled, so has a NPV of zero and a cashflow.

The first parameter of `ForwardRateAgreement()` is the settle date of the FRA. The second, maturity, is the end date. So for a spot 3x6, the start date is 3m from now, and the maturity is 6m from now.

Amending this line to:

`dayConvention = ql.Actual360()`

and

`fra = ql.ForwardRateAgreement(calendar.advance(startDate,ql.Period(3,ql.Months)), calendar.advance(startDate,ql.Period(6,ql.Months)), ql.Position.Long, rate, notional, index, spotCurveHandle)`

will give you the dates for a spot 3x6 FRA (30-Sep-20 -> 30-Dec-20).

Output:
`NPV: -262.08622386063985`

NB. In the QuantLib example for FRA's, they use a selection of FRA market rates to build a `PiecewiseLogLinearDiscount` curve to value the FRA, rather than a zero curve, and I guess it is the subtle differences between the two which is leading to the slight change in forward rate (and hence NPV). The implied forward rate for the FRA comes out at 4.937% ... ie not 5%, which also increases the NPV. In practice, if you are trying to price FRAs then build a curve using market FRA quotes.

Comment: Thank you. I also asked the question on this [link](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/67801/pricing-a-forward-rate-agreement-using-quantlib-python) and got the same answer from Luigi.